# MOSFET increase voltage on load is too slow

Tags: mosfet, 555

Can someone help me correct turn on N-MOSFET transistor (M1)?

[image]

I want control Load using MOSFET with start delay. The delay based on RC with discharge. As a load use Monostable NE555:

[image]

When the transistor is turned on, the circuit based on the NE555 does not work. Probably the problem is that the voltage supplied to the NE555 circuit is too slow.

**I connected two circuits into one:**

[image]

**Second version of the circuit:**

[image]

Comment: Ain't that a n-mos? you can use the reset pin of NE555 to hold off the load.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do -- if you're connecting the 555 circuit as the "load", then *where* are you connecting it?  If you're using the 555 circuit instead of the MOSFET delay circuitry, then _say so_.  In either case, please _edit your question_ for clarity.

Comment: Right, i use n-mos, not p-mos. My mistake sorry. The NE555 circuit is conected between Drain (M1) and power supply +5.8V. The tac-switch which you can see on the second schematic is removed (bridge).

Comment: Might I suggest adding the ‘complete’ circuit to your post?

Comment: Your design keeps the MOSFET in the linear range for a long time where it will dissipate power and possibly fry. But without all the details that is just a best guess.

Comment: I connected both circuits into one exactly as I have on my bench. I think about add Zener diode e.g. 3V3 (above Vth) near the gate of the transistor. When voltage exceed 3.3V on capacitor C1 the MOS will be turn on. Is it good idea?

Comment: Disconnecting the Gnd pin of 555 is not a good approach. It is better to use a trigger pin to control/trigger 555. The startup delay circuit with Mosfet seems OK to me.

Comment: Ok, I use now trigger pin to control NE555 by MOSFET. The idea is make about 5 second delay after plug 5.8V and then turn on LED (D3) on ~1 second and after that turn off. But when MOSFET is turn on the NE555 is not triggering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found proper solution for this problem. I used operational amplifier for control MOSFET.

[image]